Reporting the output of multiple variables with corresponding statistics
I'm currently working on the statistical analysis for a clinical study and I would like to report multiple contingency tables (the output of CROSSTABS from SPSS which is replicated by descr::CrossTabs or other packages) as well as continuous variables in the same final table, with some simple statistics.
Here an example of what I would like to achieve at once:

In short it would include median (percentile-percentile) for continuous variables with Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney p values and a simpler version of the SPSS output with column totals.

So far the best code I found to create this is the following:
set.seed(123)
member <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
author <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
review <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
publish <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
pay <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(member, author, review, 
                 publish, pay) |>
  dplyr::mutate(across(c(review, publish, pay),
                       ~cut(.,
                            breaks = c(-Inf, 4.5, 5.5, Inf),
                            labels = c("No", "Maybe", "Yes"),
                            include.lowest = TRUE), 
                       .names = "{.col}_group"))

cv <- c("review_group", "publish_group", "pay_group")
v <- map(
  cv,
  ~ tbl_cross(data = df, row = .x, col = member,
              missing = "no", percent = "column") |>
    add_p(pvalue_fun = label_style_pvalue(digits = 3))
)

tbl_merge(v)

Slightly modified from How to generate cross table for multiple variables in the column using dplyr and gtsummary.
However the resulting tables are adjacent, Total is in the same row (which isn't optimal as some values are missing...) and I would like the tables to be merged in a vertical way.
How could I do this?
Thank you.
